# Is my QUBES-OS master signing key right or wrong?

Tags: security, digital-signature, qubes-os

**i just tried to verify my Qubes Master Signing Key with this description:**

https://www.qubes-os.org/security/verifying-signatures/#1-get-the-qubes-master-signing-key-and-verify-its-authenticity

**I used this download:**

gpg2 --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 0x427F11FD0FAA4B080123F01CDDFA1A3E36879494

**Then i tried to verify the public key and fingerprint:**

gpg2 --edit-key 0x36879494

gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.4; Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

pub  rsa4096/DDFA1A3E36879494
     created: 2010-04-01  expires: never       usage: SC
     trust: unknown       validity: unknown
[ unknown] (1). Qubes Master Signing Key

gpg> fpr

pub   rsa4096/DDFA1A3E36879494 2010-04-01 Qubes Master Signing Key
 Primary key fingerprint: 427F 11FD 0FAA 4B08 0123  F01C DDFA 1A3E 3687 9494

**At the Qubes site, (and at other websites, the Pub Name is *different* to mine, but the key fingerprint is the same as you can see here:**

pub   4096R/36879494 2010-04-01
      Key fingerprint = 427F 11FD 0FAA 4B08 0123  F01C DDFA 1A3E 3687 9494
uid   Qubes Master Signing Key

Am i right, that i cannot trust the downloaded Master signing key?!
(pub rsa4096/DDFA1A3E36879494 & 4096R/36879494**are different, but the 
Fingerprint output is the same...)*

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> pub rsa4096/DDFA1A3E36879494 & 4096R/36879494**are different

Not really they're not. This is not a "pub name" of any kind – it describes the key's parameters. (The *actual* name is "Qubes Master Signing Key".)

- `rsa4096` and `4096R` both mean the same thing – 4096-bit RSA key.
- `DDFA1A3E36879494` and `36879494` both are the "key IDs" which are the last 16 and 8 digits of the fingerprint (also called "long" and "short" key ID).

Older GnuPG versions used 8-digit key IDs, however, it is *very* easy to generate keys with colliding key IDs, and there are many accidental collisions known already. Switching to longer (16-digit) key IDs somewhat alleviates the problem. The latest GnuPG releases do not use keyids at all – they show just the whole 40-digit fingerprint.

In older versions the only possible key types were RSA, DSA, and ElGamal (all of which had very similar key size ranges), marked `R`, `D`, `E` respectively. Recently several other key types were added, such as ECDSA and EdDSA which no longer fit into this pattern due to using curve names rather than bit-lengths and the old scheme could only create confusion. (For example, does "E" now mean "ElGamal" or "ECDSA-P521" or "Ed25519"?)